# Problems with results in program related o binary code written in C

Tags: c, binary

I have been doing a program in which I need to print an array of int, 1 and 0, the signal, floating comma... The problem is that when I put a negative number the cycle is infinite and my array of bits is not giving the right results. Help me please! Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float number;
int bits[31];
char sinal;
int expoente;
float mantissa;
int i;
int s;
float j;
int f;

void getSignal(float number){
    if(number < 0){
        sinal = '-';
        bits[0] = 1;
        number = number * -1; //passar a positivo p dpos dividir
    }
    else if(number > 0){
        sinal = '+';
        bits[0] = 0;
    }
}

//o numero de vezes q vo dividir o float ate dar um numero aceitavel p mantissa é o meu expoente, se for a dividir incrementa, etc...
void numberDivision(float number){
    while(number > 2){
        number = number/2;
        expoente++;
    }
    /*while(number < 1){
      number = number * 2;
      expoente--;
      }*/
    mantissa = number;
}

void expoenteToBinario(){ //i-127 = expoente  <=>  i = 127 + expoente  parto sempre do negativo
    i = 127+expoente;
    s = 7; //comeca a 7 p fzer a ordem ao contrario
    while(s >= 1){
        bits[s] = i%2; 
        s--;
        i = i/2;
    }
}

void mantissaToBinario(){
    if(mantissa < 2 && mantissa > 1){
        j = mantissa - 1;
    }
    while(j < 1){ 
        j = j * 2;
        if(j<1)
            bits[f] = 0;
        else 
            bits[f] = 1;
    }
}

void escreve_IEEE(char sinal, int expoente, float mantissa){
    printf("sinal: %c\n", sinal);
    printf("expoente: %d\n", expoente);
    printf("mantissa: %.8f\n", mantissa);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    scanf("%f", &number);
    getSignal(number);
    numberDivision(number);
    expoenteToBinario();
    mantissaToBinario();
    int x = 0;
    while(x<=31)
    {
        printf("%d", bits[x]);
        x++;
    }
    escreve_IEEE(sinal, expoente, mantissa);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must not access `bits[31]`, which is out-of-range.

Comment: ?? didn't understand what you meant

Answer (score 0):

In the functions `getSignal()` and `numberDivision()`, you are modifying the local variable (argument), so the sugn negation won't affect the global variable.
Though using unnecessary global variables is not good, *you* decided to use them in *this code*, so *you* should stick on that and refactoring should be after what properly works is built.

Also note that you must not access out-of-range of arrays. Only `bits[0]` to `bits[30]` are available for `int bits[31];`, so allocate one more elements to use `bits[31]`.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float number;
int bits[32];
char sinal;
int expoente;
float mantissa;
int i;
int s;
float j;
int f;

void getSignal(){
    if(number < 0){
        sinal = '-';
        bits[0] = 1;
        number = number * -1; //passar a positivo p dpos dividir
    }
    else if(number > 0){
        sinal = '+';
        bits[0] = 0;
    }
}

//o numero de vezes q vo dividir o float ate dar um numero aceitavel p mantissa é o meu expoente, se for a dividir incrementa, etc...
void numberDivision(){
    while(number > 2){
        number = number/2;
        expoente++;
    }
    /*while(number < 1){
      number = number * 2;
      expoente--;
      }*/
    mantissa = number;
}

void expoenteToBinario(){ //i-127 = expoente  <=>  i = 127 + expoente  parto sempre do negativo
    i = 127+expoente;
    s = 7; //comeca a 7 p fzer a ordem ao contrario
    while(s >= 1){
        bits[s] = i%2; 
        s--;
        i = i/2;
    }
}

void mantissaToBinario(){
    if(mantissa < 2 && mantissa > 1){
        j = mantissa - 1;
    }
    while(j < 1){ 
        j = j * 2;
        if(j<1)
            bits[f] = 0;
        else 
            bits[f] = 1;
    }
}

void escreve_IEEE(){
    printf("sinal: %c\n", sinal);
    printf("expoente: %d\n", expoente);
    printf("mantissa: %.8f\n", mantissa);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    scanf("%f", &number);
    getSignal();
    numberDivision();
    expoenteToBinario();
    mantissaToBinario();
    int x = 0;
    while(x<=31)
    {
        printf("%d", bits[x]);
        x++;
    }
    escreve_IEEE();
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:** The functions `expoenteToBinario()` and `mantissaToBinario()` are also wrong:

- The exponential part is 8-bit long, not 7 bits.
- The exponential part has to be zero if the value is zero.
- You have never updated `f`, so only the sign bit is overwritten in `mantissaToBinario()`.
- The conditions for `while` and `if` were the same, so it wouldn't do the right conversion. Also you have to decrement `j` when it becomes 1 or more.

Corrected code:

```
void expoenteToBinario(){ //i-127 = expoente  <=>  i = 127 + expoente  parto sempre do negativo
    i = 127+expoente;
    if(mantissa == 0) i = 0;
    s = 8; //comeca a 8 p fzer a ordem ao contrario
    while(s >= 1){
        bits[s] = i%2; 
        s--;
        i = i/2;
    }
}

void mantissaToBinario(){
    if(mantissa < 2 && mantissa > 1){
        j = mantissa - 1;
    }
    f = 9;
    while(f <= 31){ 
        j = j * 2;
        if(j<1){
            bits[f] = 0;
        }else{
            bits[f] = 1;
            j -= 1;
        }
        f++;
    }
}
```

With this code, I got almost right value for input `3.14` and `300.14`, but some of the last digits were wrong.

This program also doesn't support numbers which are not normalized.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't change nothing, but thanks anyway :D